# Python 3.4.2, reading from text file and printing accordingly

Tags: python

i have a computer science project and i can’t find anywhere how to figure this out. I need python to ask for input and if input is equal to a text file then it moves onto next input if it’s the same.  If not it repeats the question: “please enter your name” so far I've got:

```
Player_1 = input(“please enter your name”)
```

Then need what I've said above. The text file only needs to contain two names. I am relatively new to python, hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. IT can be very helpful to share some code you have tried. This allows other users to provide the most relevant support. Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: As a simple tip for your coding problem, try reading the lines from the file at the start and saving them in a data structure before you even check for user input.

Comment: Read [pythonforbeginners.com/loops](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/loops/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response
Minus the file reading I guess but that makes this a somewhat broad question rather than asking for a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file "filename.txt" should use a symbol to separate names.

Let's say a comma, so your file should look like this:

filename.txt:
Name1,Name2

You could use:

```
txt=open("filename.txt",'r').read()
```

to get your file content as string.

```
namesList=txt.split(',')
```

to get a list of the names in the file:

```
["Name1","Name2"]
```

then a loop to check inputs of the user:

```
userEntry=''
while userEntry not in namesList:
    userEntry=input("please enter your name")
```

At the end, userEntry is equal to one of the two names in your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it